# app crash on simulator Xcode 13.3 Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, simulator, xcode13.3.1

My app works perfectly fine on device but not on simulator since the xcode and Mac OS update.

All the frameworks added to project show in red color and when I try to run the app it crash with following error.

dyld[1869]: Symbol not found: *OBJC_CLASS*$_ACAccountStore
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
Expected in: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-dsadygszxtqmitctiebdebgbzedo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Accounts.framework/Accounts

Comment: Did you clean your build folder ?

Comment: yes, I did all, its got resolved now. after I renamed my framework to Account instead of Accounts, which is system framework

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your framework name do not match with any of system framework. renaming framework helped me resolved this issue.